# How to count pages in a Postscript

Tags: c#, postscript

I'm developing a C# Console Application and have to count the pages of a PostScript file. Is there an easyer way to count the pages other then parsing the text in the file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the file contains an arbitrary PostScript program, the only way is to execute the file, perhaps after redefining the `showpage` operator to count the number of pages.

If the file follows the DSC conventions, then you can count `%%Page` comments or perhaps directly use `%%Pages` if present.

See also http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/PostScript_FAQ#How_to_count_pages_in_a_PS_file.3F.